# JSON org.json.JSONException: Value Error of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I know this error has ben solved by a lot of people lately, but i'm more likely a beginner and i'd like to know where I'm wrong since I wrote this code one year ago, and I quite need it now :/

Thanks in advance to look up over my code,

I know it's 95% sure the solution would be encoding UTF-8 without BOM. but how do you do that? I keep looking in the thread and it appears I don't understand at all....

Really thank you for answering.

```
package com.example.gsb;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;


import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GSB extends Activity {

    //Login
    EditText loginText, passwordText;
    String login, resultat;
    Button bouton;

    //Praticien
    TextView visiteur;
    String nom_visiteur, prenom_visiteur, id_visiteur;

    //
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // récupération de l'EditTextLogin grâce à son ID
        loginText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextLogin);
        // récupération de l'EditTextPassword grâce à son ID
        passwordText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPassword);
        // récupération du boutton grâce à son ID
        bouton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BoutonEnvoyer);

        //on applique un écouteur d'évenement au clique bouton
        bouton.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        //On garde le login pour l'utiliser dans la vue praticien
                        login = loginText.getText().toString();                 


                        try{
                            //Création des paramètres à envoyer au serveur web
                            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                            parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", loginText.getText().toString()));
                            parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordText.getText().toString()));

                            //Envoi des paramètres aux script PHP
                            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://hiddenz.esy.es/gsb_android/login_verify.php");

                            //Envoie des données
                            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametres));

                            //Réponse du serveur web
                            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

                            //Récupération de la réponse en JSON
                            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

                            //On parcourt l'objet JSON pour avoir la valeur de "result"
                            resultat = jsonobject.getString("result");
                        } catch(JSONException e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Erreur JSON " + e.toString());
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Erreur connexion http " + e.toString());
                        }
                        //Si resultat JSON = ok on passe a la vue praticien sinon on affiche une erreur
                        if(resultat.matches("ok")){
                            Visiteur(v);
                        }else{
                            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewErreur)).setText("Login ou password incorrect");
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    public void Visiteur (View v){
        //Affichage de la vue
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visiteur);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewVisiteur)).setText("Bienvenue " + login);
        try{
            //Création des paramètres à envoyer au serveur web
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> parametres = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            parametres.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", login));

            //Envoi des paramètres aux script PHP
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://laurentlepee.com/bts/androidGSB/visiteur.php");

            //Envoi des données
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parametres));

            //Réponse du serveur web
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            //Récupération de la réponse en JSON
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

            //On parcourt l'objet JSON pour avoir la valeur de "result"
            id_visiteur = jsonobject.getString("id_vis");
            nom_visiteur = jsonobject.getString("nom_vis");
            prenom_visiteur = jsonobject.getString("prenom_vis");

        } catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erreur JSON " + e.toString());
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Erreur connexion http " + e.toString());
        }
        if (nom_visiteur.contentEquals("null")) {

        } else {
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewVisiteur)).setText("Vous êtes : " + nom_visiteur + " " + prenom_visiteur + " " + id_visiteur);
        }

    }




    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
            while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Wow, thank you guys for that fast answer. Actually you really speak like you were talking to someone who didn't code for a year. So I don't really know how to check the json, neither log the string.. forgot all of this :/

When I put an incorrect password it jumps to the "wrong login, try again", and while I put the good password, it jumps to nothing cause of this error, the program get closed.

Comment: Your response is a string not a json. Check the json

Comment: Apart from that you are doing network operation on the ui thread itself which is also wrong

Comment: You should try to log the string you are trying to parse to json

Comment: I don't understand how to do what you guys tell me :(

Answer (score 0):

well,
from your edit, if wrong password, it works fine, and when correct login, it fails.

i see your problem is server side
because when correct login, your service or page (server side) try to build json, at this point you get server error, causing some string to be returned instead of json

it might be, warning variable xxx is not defined

or database field not found ...

** to log something, use `Log.d("mytag",jsonResult )` you can see that in logcat.

or use `System.out.print(jsonResult );` its not really good to trace or log code using this, but still do the trick